# f:event type before actions are called

Tags: jsf-2

I am using this in a page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.logoutIfNotAuthenticated}"/>
```

it works. However, the listener is called after a action is called (for example, by clicking by a commandButton).

Is there a system-event which will be called at first?

I have tried it with "preValidate", but this will not work, if the form has no validation requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use filters to achieve the session management?, that way all request could get automaticly and then being redirected or processed

Comment: I am using a filter actually, which is working, too. I only want to try the new f:event-type for whatever reason (easier, performance, ..). However, I guess, I will use the filter.

Comment: Lol, I know, but the pase listener are intended for other reasons, the best way is with filters since you'll be avoiding error cheking and other stuff, because the request get to the filters first, the phase listeners are for more specifical needs like pre render some speciall component or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Although using filter is a good solution, preRenderView event should work properly and the listener should fire before the view is rendered. I used it many times to navigate away from the requested view in the event if the  user does not have access to the requested page for example.